# Determining flow amount along stream using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.2

I have DEM with resolution 20m and also stream network map in shape format, isohyetal map in shape format. I have also historic numerical data for rainfall, runoff and temperature from 1970-2000 for just one gauging station in the area 10x14 km = 140 sqm.

Can anybody give me idea how can I calculate the stream flow amount(Q) for entire area and especially along the main stream, using ArcGIS 9.2?

Answer (score 2):

Give this script a try: http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14481

If I recall correctly, you select stream segments, run this macro (tie the macro to a button on a custom toolbar) and it calculates the flow accumulation for the selected segments. I remember that we had to make a few tweaks to get it to work with our data.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are talking about hydrologic problem, and you need ArcHydro for that, I believe (or something similar if they exists).   There is a link to file for version ArcGIS 9.2 in http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/datamodel/detail/15, and it includes documentations and tutorials in pdf.